# Can a group of people be an actor in a Use Case diagram?

Tags: uml, actor, object-oriented-analysis

I have this scenario where a group organizer will book a group of staff in the system.  What kind of actor will be the group of staff? Does it make sense to name it like A13-staffGroup?  Is this allowed? Or should it be just A13-Staff instead?

Comment: Depends on your domain whether a group is somewhat different from a single person. Based on what you wrote it can't be decided.

Comment: Will the group interact collectively with the software ?